# использование маски(inputmask) для динамически подгружаемых элементов

Tags: javascript, ajax, inputmask

Вся страница динамически подружается с данных получаемых от сервера примерно таким образом:

```js
$('<input>')
  .attr('id', 'input' + id)
  .attr('type', 'text')
  .appendTo('#par' + i);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Также от сервера приходит информация о шаблоне маски для каждого поля ввода текста. Но почему-то не получается присвоить маску полю, которое строиться именно динамически, на статисеских полях все работает. В чем может быть причина и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Приведите полный код, как подгружаются элементы, и как навешивается маска

Comment: была глупая ошибка. не связанная с этим